# CSS using div as a mask

Tags: html, css

So, I've been trying to use an hamburger menu I made from 3 stacked div tags as a mask for a background with a color gradient (the red/yellow one, the blue/violet one is the main background).
The result I would like to achieve is this: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyhwR.png)
I know I could simply use a svg file of the hamburger, but I would like to do this with the div tags I made so I can later animate them to transition in a x icon, as this whole thing is to create a sidebar.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #c850c0, #4158d0);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.hamburger{
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #faf617, #ff0000);
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    padding: 1px;
    left: 20px;
}

.line{
    width: 30px;
    height: 4px;
    margin: 7px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your can also shipmate svg, so no need to use divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give them the same background and play with position to create the effect:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #c850c0, #4158d0);
}

.hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  /* add this to see that it's the same
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #faf617, #ff0000);  */
}

.line {
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 7px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #faf617, #ff0000);
  background-size:calc(100% + 2*7px) calc(100%*3 + 4*7px);
}
.line:nth-child(1) {
  background-position:-7px -7px;  /*7  = 7*1 + 0*4*/
}
.line:nth-child(2) {
  background-position:-7px -18px; /*18 = 7*2 + 1*4*/
}
.line:nth-child(3) {
  background-position:-7px -29px; /*29 = 7*3 + 2*4*/
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Another idea where you can use mask with a pseudo element. The trick is to not set position to `.line` to make the pseudo element positionned relatively to the hamburger then you hide the overflow using mask:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #c850c0, #4158d0);
}

.hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  /* add this to see that it's the same
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #faf617, #ff0000);  */
}

.line {
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 7px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
          mask:linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
}
.line:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #faf617, #ff0000);

}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, the second idea is the one that seems the simplest to me. But I wonder, what if I change the position, orientation and number of the lines to make them transition into an x shape? Will they move without shifting or moving the gradient?

Comment: @pierluromani The movement will be tricky because if you will transform you will break the containing block. I am thinking about how you can do this and have animation at the same time

Comment: Also, the logic behind it isn't really clear to me. Maybe it's because I'm not really an html and css expert, but could you try to explain it to me in a "simple" way?

Comment: I searched so much on google about masks, clips, clip-paths... But the only thing I icould find is to make a mask by using standar shapes like a rectangle or a circle, nothing about making a mask using a "custom built" shape

Comment: @pierluromani the logic here is that each line will have a pseudo element placed relatively to hamburger so we have 3 exact same elements above each other. Until now it's easy. Now if I apply the mask I will show only a part of each pseudo element and I will hide what is outside the line. Basically the pseudo element is having its size/position based on the hamburger but its visible part based on line.

Comment: Ok let me try to get this straight: each line has a pseudo-object placed before it, so we're creating 3 pseudo-object, each having its own gradient and each inheriting the hamburger's width and height (I assume, correct me if I'm wrong, and if that's the case, why is that?).
With this:
-webkit-mask: linear-gradient(#fff, #fff);
            mask: linear-gradient(#fff, #fff);
(btw, why do we have almost the same line of code twice?)
each line becomes a mask that shows a part background (the pseudo-elements) based on its position. Am I right?

Comment: @pierluromani any element with position:absolute will be positionned relative to the first postionned ancestor that's why the pseudo element here consider the hamburger element and no the line element to define their size/position. I used two line for the mask because it's a new feature and I need the -webkit- version to make it working on Chrome/Safari but in the near future we will keep only the last line

Comment: Oohhhh got it! Wow man, thank you so much for the effort and expecially the patience, ahahaha, bless you!